Ошибки Stylelint
Не могу разобраться, почему плагин выдаёт предупреждения.
Код - https://codepen.io/Siegerus/pen/LYKGwax


.cost-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 29px 0 31px 20px;

    &__header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    &__number {
        margin-right: 8px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 150px;
        line-height: 83%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
    }

    &__title {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 119%;
    }

    &__price {
        margin-top: 35px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 48px;
        line-height: 125%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
    }

    &__footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    &__support, &__month {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 146%;
    }

    &__month {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cost-item">
    <div class="cost-item__header">
      <div class="cost-item__number">1</div>
      <div class="cost-item__title">блок</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cost-item__price">9 000</div>
    <div class="cost-item__footer">
      <div class="cost-item__support">Поддержка</div>
      <div class="cost-item__month">1,5 месяца</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Настройки плагина -
"plugin/selector-bem-pattern": [
        {
            "implicitComponents": true,
            "componentName": "[-a-z]+",
            "componentSelectors": {
                "initial": "^(\\.{componentName}(__[a-z]+|--[-a-z0-9]+|__[-a-z]+--[-a-z0-9]+|.[-a-z]+|__[a-z]+.[-a-z]+)?)$",
                "combined": "^.+$"
            },
            "ignoreSelectors": [
                "^\\.(no-)?js(-modal-open)?$",
                "a(\\[[a-z]+|:[a-z]+)?",
                "h[1-6]",
                "pre",
                "blockquote",
                "thead",
                "tr",
                "img",
                "img",
                "p",
                "table",
                "^&:empty",
                "#{\\$[-a-z]+}__[-a-z]+",
                "^\\*$"
            ],
        },
        {
            "severity": "warning",
            "message": "Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка"
        }

Получаю вот такое -
 14:5  ⚠  Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка  plugin/selector-bem-pattern
 23:5  ⚠  Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка  plugin/selector-bem-pattern
 38:5  ⚠  Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка  plugin/selector-bem-pattern
 44:5  ⚠  Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка  plugin/selector-bem-pattern
 50:5  ⚠  Селектор не из имени файла или БЭМ-ошибка  plugin/selector-bem-pattern

При этом, на селектор "&__price" он почему-то не ругается, на "&__header" тоже.
Буду признателен за помощь в понимании логики происходящего)

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Ну и где сам код?

Там ссылка на codepen. Но добавил и сюда тоже.
